# Optimization postgresql request

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, indexing, generate-series

How I can optimize request in postgresql?
What the best indexes I should create?

I have tried to add separate index for t_my.id,t_my.param1,t_my.param2, t_my_other.param3 but my request work slowly.
Or maybe I can make some changing or use some other functions to get a grid result array?

Size t_my 50000 rows

Size t_my_other the same 50000 rows

I need get grid of values for each combination of Serie1 and Serie2

amount, sum, Serie1, Serie2

````
EXPLAIN
WITH CTS AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT 50.0+10.0/11*generate_series(0, 11) as Serie) as tempt CROSS JOIN (SELECT 20.0+25.0/11*generate_series(0, 11) as Serie2) as t
) 

SELECT    COUNT(id) AS amount, SUM(param3) AS wire_guard, CTS.Serie, CTS.Serie2
FROM      CTS 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t_my.id,t_my.param1,t_my.param2, t_my_other.param3 FROM t_my 
          LEFT JOIN t_my_other ON t_my.id = t_my_other.id_object) as objects 
ON        objects.param1>= CTS.Serie 
AND       objects.param1<  CTS.Serie + (60.0-50)/11
AND       objects.param2>=  CTS.Serie2
AND       objects.param2<  CTS.Serie2 + (35.0-10)/11

GROUP BY  (CTS.Serie, CTS.Serie2)
ORDER BY  CTS.Serie
;
;```

plan
'GroupAggregate  (cost=1617712999.78..1649282408.93 rows=40000 width=80)'
'  Group Key: cts.serie, cts.serie2'
'  CTE cts'
'    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..12532.53 rows=1000000 width=64)'
'          ->  Result  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1000 width=32)'
'          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..20.02 rows=1000 width=32)'
'                ->  Result  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1000 width=32)'
'  ->  Sort  (cost=1617700467.25..1624014269.08 rows=2525520732 width=76)'
'        Sort Key: cts.serie, cts.serie2'
'        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=604227963.92..662200918.76 rows=2525520732 width=76)'
'              Hash Cond: (t_my_other.id_object = t_my.id)'
'              ->  Seq Scan on t_my_other (cost=0.00..8501.18 rows=297518 width=12)'
'              ->  Hash  (cost=546125388.00..546125388.00 rows=2399074074 width=72)'
'                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=434.15..546125388.00 rows=2399074074 width=72)'
'                          ->  CTE Scan on cts  (cost=0.00..20000.00 rows=1000000 width=64)'
'                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t_my  (cost=434.15..522.12 rows=2399 width=24)'
'                                Recheck Cond: ((param2 >= (cts.serie2)::double precision) AND (param2 < ((cts.serie2 + 2.2727272727272727))::double precision) AND (param1 >= (cts.serie)::double precision) AND (param1 < ((cts.serie + 0.90909090909090909091))::double precision))'
'                                ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=434.15..434.15 rows=2399 width=0)'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i_param2  (cost=0.00..216.35 rows=21592 width=0)'
'                                            Index Cond: ((param2  >= (cts.serie2)::double precision) AND (param2  < ((cts.serie2 + 2.2727272727272727))::double precision))'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i_param1  (cost=0.00..216.35 rows=21592 width=0)'
'                                            Index Cond: ((param1 >= (cts.serie)::double precision) AND (param1  < ((cts.serie + 0.90909090909090909091))::double precision))'
````

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, the sizes of the tables, the current execution plan, and an explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: That can't be the query you actually run, I can see at least one syntax error in it...  *(`ON .. AND ... ON ... AND ...`)* as well as `CTS.Serie` needing to be `CTS.Serie1`.  Please show the ***ACTUAL*** query that's slow, along with explain plans, etc, as per Gordon's comment.

Comment: That's the problem with generate_series(): it also generates an *estimated* number of rows=1000, the cathesian product blows it up to 1M. BTW: what is your Postgres version? [short fix: get rid of the CTE] And: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to PostgreSQL v12 or better, because

1. that version introduced optimizer support functions, which allow correct row count estimates for `generate_series`
2. CTEs no longet act as optimization barriers from v12 on

This should improve the execution plan and consequently the performance.